# Basic question on Open Sets

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, solution-verification, proof-explanation

I'm trying to prove the following:

> Let $X$ be a topological space, and $U \subset X$ be an open set, and $C \subset X$. Then, every open in $C \cap U$ is open in $C$.

My proof: $U \cap C$ is open in $C$, directly by definition of the subspace topology. Thus for every open $A \subset (U \cap C)$, there $\exists B \subset C$ such that $B \cap (U \cap C) = A$. So $A$ is open in $C$ as an intersection of two open sets.

Firstly, is this proof correct?

Also, apparently there's another proof that goes: Every open in $U$ is open in $X$, as $U$ is open. It follows that every open in $C \cap U$ is open in $C$. I don't understand how it follows; could someone demistify this (in a more step-by-step manner)? Thanks.

Comment: Basically just replace $U$ with $C \cap U$ and $X$ with $C$ (which works as $C \cap U$ is open in $C$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is an open set of the subspace $U \cap C$, then $A = (U\cap C)\cap B$, for some open set $B$ in $X$. $B$ need not be a subset of $C$.

But from there the conclusion holds, because $B \cap U$ os open (they are both open in $X$), hence $A$ is open in the subspace topology of $C$.

The second argument is really very similar: By saying that every open set in the subspace topology on $U$ is open in $X$, we are really saying that $U \cap O$ is open in $X$, for every open $O$ in $X$. Then consider an open set, $H$, of $C \cap U$: $H = (C \cap U) \cap O$, for some open $O$ in $X$. But $U \cap O$ is an open set of $U$ and hence an open set of $X$. Hence $H$ must be open in $C$, by the definition of the subspace topology on $C$.

Unless I'm missing something, this second argument is essentially redundant. It's just asserting the fact that $U \cap O$ is open in $X$. But this is immediate from the openness of both $U$ and $O$ anyway; you don't really need to invoke the subspace of $U$ to achieve this.

Comment: Hi, to clarify my first proof, $U \cap C$ is open in $C$, so let $C$ have the induced subspace topology, and let $U \cap C$ have the induced subspace topology from $C$. We know from standard topological results that the topology for $U \cap C$ above coincides with the topology for $U \cap C$ induced from $X$. So $B$ is a subset of $C$.

Comment: @Albert Ah OK, I didn't realise you were trying to take the subspace topology of $U \cap C$ with respect to $C$. We don't need to do this to prove the desired result.

Comment: @Albert But I also don't follow your argument. Any open set in the subspace topology of $U\cap C$ wrt to $C$ is of the form $(U \cap C) \cap (C \cap B)$, where $B$ is open in $X$. This is of course just $(U \cap C) \cap B$, which is indeed an open set in the subspace wrt to $X$. But $B$ is still just an open set in $X$, I don't see where we are getting that $B$ is a subset of $C$.

Comment: Oh, I think the convention that I was taught may be confusing. The $B$ that I am referring to is $C \cap B$ in your comment. So we immediately start by letting $B$ be a subset of $C$ instead of starting from $B$ open in $X$, reducing it to $C \cap B$, and letting $C \cap B$ be open in $C$.

Comment: @Albert OK I see your logic now. It works, but it's totally unnecessary to consider anything but the subspaces with respect to $X$.